# Do JavaScript anonymous functions protect against client-side editing?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a game and have recently read up about anonymous functions inside JavaScript. To my understanding they wrap content and make any variables inside local to the function rather than being in the global namespace. My question is, does this stop users from editing variables inside the anonymous function?

I checked it out myself and when attempting to change the variable 'a' (from a little JS file I created wrapped in the anonymous function) in the Chrome console I was told it was undefined hinting that users wouldn't be able to change them.

Does this fully protect these variables or can players edit the variables in some other way?

Thanks

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside your anonymous function.

Comment: Nothing fully protects client-side variables

Comment: What's a breakpoint, Mat? And ok thanks sroes. The game is multiplayer so I'll be validating any changes on the server-side anyway, just thought I'd check.

Comment: You could a. redefine that part of the JS, b. alter it or whatever is possible with Chrome's standard Inspector tools.

Comment: @11684 Looks like I need to do my research about these 'define' thingies. Would you mind briefly explaining what the purpose of them is?

Comment: Well, say you got a global object `foo` with a few private variables (say `a` and `b`). I could look at the source, copy paste that global `foo` object to a text editor, make the private variables public and type in the console `window.foo = ...` (with what I would have in my text editor instead of the `...`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will help, but Chrome, for example, allows me to open up developer tools and edit javascript source directly. There is no way to fully protect javascript variables. Users will be able to change anything they want. Make it harder by keeping variables locally scoped (by using an anonymous function for example) and minifying your code.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Will accept this answer as soon as the timer is up. For testing I shall just leave it off for now and when public I will put it back in anonymous function. I prefer having it off just so I can test the value of some variables... :)

Comment: Good luck! As somebody else mentioned, using breakpoints and watch expressions might also be a useful method for debugging. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints